# Character recognition from image with low contrast

Tags: python, opencv, keras

I have images (about 1000) with different numbers. Using opencv I extracted ROI from these images. Here's a small sample:

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]

And I don't know how to extract these numbers or identify them. For opencv have a small threshold. I tried VGGnet keras (I rotated each image 1 degree to create 360 images as input for tensorflow), but the control image was mostly not recognized. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You can use this approach with python: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/

Comment: Isn’t this a bit broad for Stack Overflow, and possibly off topic? See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Are you trying to extract the text? Please post any code that you have tried

Comment: Pyimagesearch Tesseract - OCR recognition does not work because the numbers have low contrast to the background.I tried cv.Canny, cv.findContours, cv.threshold... According to https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/10/keras-tutorial-how-to-get-started-with-keras-deep-learning-and-python/, I tried to create NN. But the trained network did not recognize new images. I think the biggest problem is that the color of numbers and background color are almost the same. Although as a person I read the numbers well ...